# Nodejs on firefox OS

Tags: firefox-os

Firefox OS could host nodejs app's in an offline mode? Just like a normal app just because it uses only HTML5 (till today) form deploying app's to this new plattform.

Or the new system uses only apps as webservices like normal html does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, if you mean creating and hosting a web application in Node.JS, and using that same web application when offline, then the answer is **yes**.

You should look into what **[hosted](https://marketplace.firefox.com/developers/docs/hosted) applications** are and enhancing your application with [offline capabilities](https://marketplace.firefox.com/developers/docs/apps_offline) by using the cache manifest for caching application resources and using the browser/local storage for storing application data for offline use.

Answer (score 1):

You can not run Node.JS on Firefox OS. The marked answer is wrong. Node.JS itself doesn't run on browsers or mobile devices. [JXcore](https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore), a mobile and embedded distro of Node.JS works on iOS and Android. However it doesn't work on Firefox OS for now.

Actually there is no technical bottleneck that keeps JXcore from running on Firefox OS. JXcore embeds SpiderMonkey in addition to V8. The problem is Firefox OS doesn't allow any native code.